# Iterate taking data from mongodb and inserting it into HTML

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, express

I have my Mongo DB, my routes and my controllers, this is a page that opens when I click on a link, what it has to show are the details of a trip but I don't know how to do it dynamically, I have to make sure that it takes into account dynamically the information and add it to my html with a 'p'.

Now it takes data only in this way creating multiple paragraphs.

```
output.append(p);
output.append(p1);

p.textContent = obj.destinazione;
p1.textContent = obj.durata
```

````
var id_tour = window.location.href.split("/tours/page/")[1];
var array_tours;
const output = document.querySelector(".output");
const output1 = document.createElement("div");
const url = "/tours/" + id_tour;
const p = document.createElement("p");
const p1 = document.createElement("p");
output.append(output1);
output.append(p);
output.append(p1);

window.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", () => {
  loadData();
});

function loadData() {
  fetch(url)
    .then((res) => {
      return res.json();
    })
    .then((data) => {
      console.log("data", data);
      addToPage(data);
    })
    .catch((err) => {
      console.log(err);
    });
}


    function addToPage(obj) {
    
    p.textContent = obj.destinazione;
    p1.textContent = obj.durata;
    }

```***emphasized text***
````

Comment: Please edit this question and    1) explain what is not happening and an example of what you want to happen   2) show the mongodb parts.    There is no mongodb in your code samples.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

HTML CODE:

```
<div class="output">
  <p id="destinazione"></p>
  <p id="durata"></p>
</div>
```

JavaScript code:

```
const id_tour = window.location.href.split("/tours/page/")[1];
const outputDestinazione = document.getElementById("destinazione");
const outputDurata = document.getElementById("durata");
const url = "/tours/" + id_tour;

window.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", () => {
  loadData();
});

function loadData() {
  fetch(url)
    .then((res) => res.json())
    .then((data) => {
      console.log("data", data);
      addToPage(data);
    })
    .catch((err) => {
      console.log(err);
    });
}

function addToPage(obj) {
  outputDestinazione.textContent = obj.destinazione;
  outputDurata.textContent = obj.durata;
}
```

In this code:

The HTML structure includes two

elements with unique IDs,
destinazione and durata, where you want to display the destination
and duration of the trip.

In the JavaScript code, we retrieve these elements by their IDs using
getElementById() and store them in outputDestinazione and
outputDurata variables.

When the page loads (DOMContentLoaded event), we call the loadData()
function to fetch the trip details from your MongoDB.

The addToPage() function then updates the text content of the
outputDestinazione and outputDurata elements with the data from the
fetched object.